# Envato theme check

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget

I have converted HTML to Wordpress. That's why I have created some custom widgets and it's working fine. Now I am trying to solve error using Envato theme check plugin. I have solved most of the waring but can't solve. I can't understand what is the problem of this error?[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the themeforest guideline, registering new widgets are not allowed inside the theme. register_widget is a plugin teritory function and should be called from a plugin. I suggest you to put that the code into a plugin and make that plugin required in the TGMPA list.

You can find a guideline [here](https://www.wordpress-studio.io/basic-guidelines-to-approve-a-wordpress-theme-in-themeforest-part-1/)